# changing css class of div works then changes back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 css classes and a js function that is called by a link. the js function is supposed to change the class of a div from one to another, and when I use the dev tool in chrome I can see it switch to it then back again. heres various code pieces:

js file:

```
function resetButtons()
{
    document.getElementById("appsButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("servicesButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("aboutusButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("ourresumeButton").className = "navBarButton";
    console.log("Animation complete.");
}

function buttonPress()
{
    resetButtons();
    document.getElementById("appsButton").className = "navBarButtonSelected";
}
```

I changed the code to this, still no success:

```
function appsButtonPress()
{
    document.getElementById("appsButton").className = "navBarButtonSelected";
    document.getElementById("servicesButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("aboutUsButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("ourResumeButton").className = "navBarButton";
}

function servicesButtonPress()
{
    document.getElementById("appsButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("servicesButton").className = "navBarButtonSelected";
    document.getElementById("aboutUsButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("ourResumeButton").className = "navBarButton";
}

function aboutUsButtonPress()
{
    document.getElementById("appsButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("servicesButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("aboutUsButton").className = "navBarButtonSelected";
    document.getElementById("ourResumeButton").className = "navBarButton";
}

function ourResumeButtonPress()
{
    document.getElementById("appsButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("servicesButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("aboutUsButton").className = "navBarButton";
    document.getElementById("ourResumeButton").className = "navBarButtonSelected";
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
                    <a href="" onClick="appsButtonPress();" class="navLink">
                        <div class="navBarButton" id="appsButton">
                        Apps
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" onClick="servicesButtonPress();" class="navLink">
                        <div class="navBarButton" id="servicesButton">
                        Services
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" onClick="aboutUsButtonPress();" class="navLink">
                        <div class="navBarButton" id="aboutUsButton">
                        About Us
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" onClick="ourResumeButtonPress" class="navLink">
                        <div class="navBarButton" id="ourResumeButton">
                        Our Resume
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
```

Comment: oh sorry I dont want it to change back lol

Comment: What is back and what is forward? _"navBarButton"_ or _"navBarButtonSelected"_. Your code call `resetButtons()` function in which you set _"navBarButton"_ for `#appsButton`, then `resetButtons()` return and `buttonPress()` set `#appsButton` to _"navBarButtonSelected"_. If _"navBarButtonSelected"_ is a _back_, then remove line `document.getElementById("appsButton").className = "navBarButtonSelected"` or place call `resetButtons()` on last line of `buttonPress()`

Comment: its supposed to end up having the #appsbutton using "navbarbuttonselected" and the rest using regular "navbarbutton". they all start out using "navbarbutton" before the function call to "buttonPress".

Comment: Show us the rest of your HTML/JS that makes these functions get called.  My guess is that you click on a link, execute one of these functions, then you don't cancel the default behavior of the click and the link href fires and reloads your page causing it to appear to revert.  You probably need to call `e.preventDefault()` in your click handler.

Comment: posted updated js and html Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: YAY!!! i added the event pram and the preventdefault call and it all works!! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Quiet a bit of code todo something simple.

[Heres a solution/example](http://jsfiddle.net/3raUa/4/)

Regards.